# How to know the version of facebook android sdk in node_modules/react-native-fbsdk?

Tags: react-native, facebook-android-sdk, react-native-fbsdk

For iOS we can look at the FBSDKCoreKit.h it states the SDK version there.

Is there something similar for Android? How do I know which facebook SDK version it's on?

Would be better if there's a mapping of react-native-fbsdk version to facebook android/ios SDK and graph api versions being used.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
cd android/.idea/libraries
ls
```

Now Look at file with a name like: facebook_android_sdk_4_22_0.xml

The version is in the file name.